# ¿Alguna manera de regresar a una carpeta anterior?

Tags: php, web

Estoy desarrollando un repositorio web, y estoy usando las funciones dir(),openddir() de php y demás. y lo que quiero lograr es que cuando este adentro de una carpeta pueda regresar a la anterior... */ Este es el codigo que tengo para mi repositorio, si hay mejores maneras para desarollar un repositorio, estoy al pendiente.
he visto tutoriales de como hacerlo, pero solo llegan en la parte de como abrir carpetas y mostrar contenido.

---

```
 -----------Index.php--------------    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        load_folder_list();

        function load_folder_list() {
            var action = "fetch";
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: action
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#folder_table').html(data);
                }
            })
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.abrir', function() {
        var folder_name = $(this).data("name");
        var action = "view";
        $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                action: action,
                folder_name: folder_name
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#folder_table').html(data);
            }
        })
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.regresa', function() {
        var folder_name = $(this).data("name");
        var action = "regresa";
        $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                action: action,
                folder_name: folder_name
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#folder_table').html(data);
            }
        })
    });
</script>

</html>
-----------------------------action.php-----------------------
<?php
   if (isset($_POST["action"])) {

    if ($_POST["action"] == "fetch") {
      $listar = null;
      $directorio = opendir("Contenedor/");
      $listar = "<table>
             <tr>
               <th>Nombre</th>
               <th colspan ='3'>Opciones</th>
             </tr>";
     while ($elemento = readdir($directorio)) {
      if ($elemento != '.' && $elemento != '..') {
        $path = 'Contenedor/' . $elemento;
        if (is_dir("$directorio".$elemento)) {

          $listar .= "<td'>NO HAY</td><tr>";
        }else {
          $listar .= "<tr>
                          <td>$elemento</td>
                          <td><button type='button' name='abrir' data-name= '".$path."'
                                  class='abrir btn btn-info btn-xs'>Abrir</button>
                          </td>
                          <td><button type='button' name='editar' data-name= '".$path."'
                                class='editar btn btn-warning btn-xs'>editar</button>
                          </td>
                          <td><button type='button' name='eliminar' data-name= '".$path."'
                                class='eliminar btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Eliminar</button>
                          </td>
                      </tr>";
        }
      }
    }
    $listar .="</table>";
    echo $listar;
  }

    if ($_POST["action"] == "view") {
          $path = $_POST["folder_name"];
          $listar = null;
        if ($data = explode(".", $_POST["folder_name"])) {
          $extension =$data[1];
          $allowed_extension = array("pdf", "docx", "png", "PNG",  "jpg", "xlsx");
          if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extension)) {
            $path = $_POST["folder_name"];
            echo '  <a href="'.$path.'" download="">Descarga</a>';
          }else {
            $directorio = opendir($_POST["folder_name"]);
            echo "<button type='button' name='regresa' data-name= '".$path."'
                  class='regresa btn btn-danger btn-xs'>regresa</button>
            </td>";
            $listar = "<table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th colspan ='3'>Opciones</th>
                    </tr>";
                    while ($elemento  = readdir($directorio)) {
                      if ($elemento != '.' && $elemento != '..') {
                          $path = $_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $elemento;
                        if (is_dir("$directorio".$elemento)) {
                          continue;
                        }else {
                          $listar .= "<tr>
                                          <td>$elemento</td>
                                          <td><button type='button' name='abrir' data-name= '".$path."'
                                                class='abrir btn btn-info btn-xs'>Abrir</button>
                                          </td>
                                          <td><button type='button' name='editar' data-name= '".$path."'
                                                class='editar btn btn-warning btn-xs'>editar</button>
                                          </td>
                                          <td><button type='button' name='eliminar' data-name= '".$path."'
                                                class='eliminar btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Eliminar</button>
                                          </td>
                                      </tr>";
                        }
                      }
                    }
            $listar .="</table>";
            echo $listar;
        }
      }
      }
      if ($_POST["action"] == "regresa") {
        $data = explode("/", $_POST["folder_name"]);
        $extension = $data[0];
        echo "$extension/";

      }
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: ya le intentaste de esta manera:  **../** esto te devuelve una carpeta desde donde se ejecuto el método

Comment: si lo intente, pero me modica mi url

Answer (score 0):

Lo he probado y funciona si colocas el código en la acción "regresa" ...

```
    if ($_POST["action"] == "regresa") {
    $data = explode("/", $_POST["folder_name"]);
    $dir = count($data);
    $extension = $data[0];
    echo "$extension/";
    view_folders($extension);
      // $extension =$data[1];


  }
}


function view_folders($extension){
  $allowed_extension = array("pdf", "docx", "png", "PNG",  "jpg", "xlsx");
  if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extension)) {
    $path = $extension;
    echo '  <a href="'.$path.'" download="">Descarga</a>';
  }else {
    $directorio = opendir($extension);
    echo "<button type='button' name='regresa' data-name= '".$path."'
          class='regresa btn btn-danger btn-xs'>regresa</button>".$path."
    </td>";
    $listar = "<table>
            <tr>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th colspan ='3'>Opciones</th>
            </tr>";
            while ($elemento  = readdir($directorio)) {
              if ($elemento != '.' && $elemento != '..') {
                  $path = $_POST["folder_name"] . '/' . $elemento;
                if (is_dir("$directorio".$elemento)) {
                  continue;
                }else {
                  $listar .= "<tr>
                                  <td>$elemento</td>
                                  <td><button type='button' name='abrir' data-name= '".$path."'
                                        class='abrir btn btn-info btn-xs'>Abrir</button>".$path."
                                  </td>
                                  <td><button type='button' name='editar' data-name= '".$path."'
                                        class='editar btn btn-warning btn-xs'>editar</button>
                                  </td>
                                  <td><button type='button' name='eliminar' data-name= '".$path."'
                                        class='eliminar btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Eliminar</button>
                                  </td>
                              </tr>";
                }
              }
            }
    $listar .="</table>";
    echo $listar;
}
}
```